# How to style span elements for weekly scheduler UI

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-controls, styles

I have a following test HTML code:

```
<div class="slider" day="mon">
  <span id="one" class="slider-segment"></span>
  <span class="slider-button" style="left: 25%;" key="1"></span>
  <span id="two" class="slider-segment"></span>
  <span id="three" class="slider-segment"></span>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```css
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 13px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.slider-segment {
    width: 100%;
    height: 13px;
    float: left;z
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slider-button {
    background-image: url(https://sys.prosmartsystem.com//images/calendar-graphic-point-active-2.png);
display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 15px;
    height: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-button::before {
      content: '';
    width: 3px;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    background-image: url(https://sys.prosmartsystem.com/images/calendar-graphic-point-arrow-left.png);
    left: -5px;
}

.slider-button::after {
      content: '';
    width: 3px;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    background-image: url(https://sys.prosmartsystem.com/images/calendar-graphic-point-arrow-right.png);
    right: -5px;
}

#one {
  left: 0%;
  width: 25%;
background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

#two {
  left: 25%;
  width: 12.5%;
background-color: rgb(176, 154, 198);
}

#three {
  left: 37.5%;
  width: 33.3333%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 143, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider" day="mon">
  <span id="one" class="slider-segment"></span>
  <span class="slider-button" style="left: 25%;" key="1"></span>
  <span id="two" class="slider-segment"></span>
  <span id="three" class="slider-segment"></span>
</div>
```

It resulst with a single dummy layout for a full segment of what needs to be  a part of weekly UI Scheduler.

I would like to style it so it looks this way:

[image]

I have a few problems here which I don't know how to adress:

1) This grey dot in the middle. How can I add "." and style it so it looks similiar to this one.
2) How to incorporate round edges exactly as shown in the picture. In-between span's should have them. Outer span's should only have left/right round edges.
3) How to have Hours and days displayed as in the example picture?

Comment: Could you update your HTML and CSS so that it better represents a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](minimal, reproducible example) for us to review and test.

Comment: It already is as minimal as it can be, I cannot take more out of it without ruining the point.

Comment: Your snippet varies greatly from the screenshot. Are you trying to achieve the exact same design and layout as the screenshot? Re: rounded edges, you would use `border-radius`. A single value for all corners or target corners using `border-bottom-left-radius` or `border-top-right-radius` as examples.

Comment: My snippet is what I know how to code, picture is example what I want to archive